# Linq Sum of child object property grouping by parent property

Tags: c#, linq, sum, grouping

Been thrashing around this for a few hours now and just can't quite seem to get it right.  Loading up a large data set via an OleDB connection so working with DataSets and DataTables

So I have the following data tables 
[image: Table structure]

What I want to do is get the sum of the JobEstimate.Quantity grouped by Job.PeriodRequired Where the Job.JobType = "Q", Job.JobGroupCode = "GOLD" and JobEstimate.ProductCode = "10000"

The best I've got so far is the below code, but is only giving me the quantity from the first estimate line

```
var periodQuantity = from je in ds.JobEstimate
            join j in ds.Job on je.JobCode equals j.JobCode
            where je.ProductCode == "10000" &&
                j.JobType == "Q" &&
                j.JobGroupCode == "GOLD"
            group je by j.PeriodRequired into g
            select new { PeriodId = g.Key, Quantity = g.Sum(e => e.Quantity) };
```

Comment: could pls share your attempted code ?

Comment: @AnuViswan Been many different attempts. Have added the most recent

Comment: I have updated my answer. Could you check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there was lack of clarity on DataType in the question, I have tried to mock it here using classes. Please change the code to fit your data types

```
public class Job
{
public string JobCode{get;set;}
public string JobName{get;set;}
public string PeriodRequired{get;set;}
public string JobType{get;set;}
public string JobGroupCode{get;set;}
public DateTime DateRequired{get;set;}
}

public class JobEstimate
{
public string JobCode{get;set;}
public string ProductCode{get;set;}
public int Qty {get;set;}
}
```

For example data

```
var jobList = new List<Job>(){
    new Job{JobCode="abc1",JobName="JobName1",PeriodRequired="1",JobType="Q",JobGroupCode="GOLD"},
    new Job{JobCode="abc2",JobName="JobName1",PeriodRequired="2",JobType="Q",JobGroupCode="GOLD"},
    new Job{JobCode="abc3",JobName="JobName1",PeriodRequired="3",JobType="R",JobGroupCode="GOLD"},
    new Job{JobCode="abc4",JobName="JobName1",PeriodRequired="1",JobType="Q",JobGroupCode="GOLD"}
    };
var jobEstimateList = new List<JobEstimate>(){
        new JobEstimate(){JobCode="abc1",ProductCode="10000",Qty=12},
        new JobEstimate(){JobCode="abc1",ProductCode="10000",Qty=11},
        new JobEstimate(){JobCode="abc2",ProductCode="10000",Qty=12},
        new JobEstimate(){JobCode="abc3",ProductCode="10000",Qty=14},
        };
```

You can get the required result as

```
var result = jobList.Join(jobEstimateList,
                job=> job.JobCode, 
                je=>je.JobCode,(job,je)=>new {
                                        JobCode=job.JobCode,
                                        JobName = job.JobName,
                                        JobType = job.JobType,
                                        JobGroupCode = job.JobGroupCode,
                                        ProductCode = je.ProductCode,
                                        PeriodRequired = job.PeriodRequired,
                                        Qty = je.Qty})
            .Where(x=>x.JobType=="Q" && x.JobGroupCode=="GOLD" && x.ProductCode=="10000")
            .GroupBy(x=> x.PeriodRequired)
            .Select(x=> new {PeriodId = x.Key,Qty= x.Sum(c=>c.Qty)});
```

Result

```
PeriodId | Qty
  1      | 23 
  2      | 12
```